# In PLPGSQL assign a variable based on result of SQL function

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql

I have a PLPGSQL function which receives an address in two parts:

```
num = '123'
location = 'main street, anytown, KS'
```

To utilize the various portions of `location` I found there is a SQL function `SPLIT_PART()` which would work how I want it to, in that, if I execute 
`SPLIT_PART(location,',',2)` it would render the 'city' portion.

I've tested this `SPLIT_PART()` function in pgAdmin4 to verify that it works how I expect it to, but I am having trouble executing this statement within the PLPGSQL environment and assigning the resulting value to a variable.

Through my searching, it appears as though using `'SELECT ... INTO ... '` is what I want to be using, but I have tried running this directly, using `EXECUTE`  or `EXECUTE QUERY` only render errors.  the latest being:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SPLIT_PART"
> ```

Attempt 1

```
DECLARE
    cn_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    SELECT split_part INTO cn_rec FROM SPLIT_PART('''|| i_location ||''', '','',2);
--ERROR:  function split_part(unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
--LINE 1: SELECT split_part             FROM SPLIT_PART('''|| i_locati...
--                                           ^
END;
```

Attempt 2

```
DECLARE
    cn_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
     EXECUTE QUERY 'SELECT split_part INTO cn_rec FROM SPLIT_PART('''|| i_location ||''', '','',2)';
--ERROR:  type "query" does not exist
--LINE 1: SELECT QUERY 'SELECT split_part INTO cn_rec FROM SPLIT_PART(...
--               ^
END;
```

Attempt 3

```
DECLARE
    cn_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SPLIT_PART('''|| i_location ||''', '','',2)' INTO cn_rec;
--ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SPLIT_PART"
--LINE 1: SPLIT_PART('Main St,Anytown', ',',2)
--        ^
END;
```

Being fairly new to PLPGSQL I'm not sure if I'm up against syntax errors, or fundamental misunderstanding of how this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you *can* use [`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW), it's simpler to use the [assignment operator `:=` (or just `=`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) to assign a single value:

```
_city := split_part(_location, ', ', 2);
```

[`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) would only be needed for dynamic SQL (building and executing SQL strings dynamically). Not for a simple assignment.

#### Demo

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dummy(_location text, OUT _city text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   _city := split_part(_location, ', ', 2);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT f_dummy('main street, anytown, KS');  -- 'anytown'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c2cc8e421126e14b2f302ce1998ce0fd)*

Related:

- [The forgotten assignment operator “=” and the commonplace “:=”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641260/939860)

Comment: Why an `out` parameter and not a function that is declared as `returns text`?

Comment: Each is valid. This is shorter, no `DECLARE` section needed. (Question is about assignment, so not returning directly.)